# short text(such as news title) analysing

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I have a bunch of news title to judge if they are erotic/out of date/subjective/negative, is there any suggestions of how to do with this problem.
I have no idea what to do. Is there any idea or solution or model or algorithm can help me？？

The number of titles is huge. *LIKE* "**12 People Missing as More Rain Forecast**". It is more like sentimental analysis.

Thx.

Comment: I can get a list of erotic words or other types. But I want higher prediction and recall.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, are you asking what to use to do sentiment analysis for the kind of data point shown above?

*I am assuming that these TITLES don't have spelling mistakes, smiles and other stuff.*

- **Stanford NLP** - Produces sentiment based on linguistics.
- **TextBlob** - Has 2 trained models for Sentiment analysis(PatternAnalyzer,Movie Review Datasets)
- **SentiWordNet** - If you want to predict sentiment based on weighted word score.

I hope it answers your query.